# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null -> Because of localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, github-pages

I deployed my React app to GitHub Pages (https://github.com/qriscilla/movie-search-application), but the homepage is not displaying what it's intended to show.

Below is what I see when I open up the app in my localhost via `npm start`
[image]

But on the GitHub Page I deployed my code to (https://qriscilla.github.io/movie-search-application/#/), it only shows the background image as such:
[image]

And when I open up the console, it gives me these two error messages:
[image]

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at O (Movies.js:8)
    at sa (react-dom.production.min.js:154)
    at qa (react-dom.production.min.js:174)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:261)
    at mu (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at pu (react-dom.production.min.js:229)
    at iu (react-dom.production.min.js:223)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:121
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at Bo (react-dom.production.min.js:120)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at O (Movies.js:8)
    at sa (react-dom.production.min.js:154)
    at qa (react-dom.production.min.js:174)
    at Sl (react-dom.production.min.js:261)
    at mu (react-dom.production.min.js:230)
    at pu (react-dom.production.min.js:229)
    at iu (react-dom.production.min.js:223)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:121
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.production.min.js:18)
    at Bo (react-dom.production.min.js:120)
```

I think it might be because it's not really storing the API data? Because Local Storage shows up blank:
[image]

Anyway, thanks in advance! All my code is available in my public repository (https://github.com/qriscilla/movie-search-application) for your review.

Comment: `All my code` please narrow it down for us.

Comment: Here is my App.js, where I set my localStorage: https://github.com/qriscilla/movie-search-application/blob/master/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that you fetch from localStorage but didn't handle the case `item movies is not exist in localStorage`

You should set a default value (empty array) for this case.

`in ./App.js` file

```
const json = localStorage.getItem('movies');
const movies = JSON.parse(json) || []; // set default value here
this.setState({movies});
```

Comment: It worked! Was not thinking that far. Thanks so much!